# Solr StopFilterFactory on index and query analyzers not working as expected

Tags: solr, lucene, django-haystack, stop-words, filterfactory

I've had set up a Solr 4 multicore instance and it is working like a charm but I've ran into a problem regarding the stopwords filter, I've not checked if the index filter is working properly ignoring the words on the stopwords_XX.txt file, but I'm quite sure that it isn't working on the query analyzer.

Ok, I've created a field type in my schema.xml where the query analyzer is as follows:

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_es.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords_es.txt"
        enablePositionIncrements="true"
        />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords_es.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

My stopwords_es.txt file is like this (but longer):

```
a
acá
ahí
ajena
ajeno
ajenas
ajenos
al
algo
algún
alguna
alguno
algunos
algunas
allá
(...)
de
(...)
y
(...)
```

So, I'm building my keyword queries splitting all keywords in a phrase and then making an OR for every word, finally boost the whole phrase. Easy to understand with an example, if a user searches something like "mayor y de buenos sentimientos" the final query will be something similar to:

```
((mayor) OR (y) OR (de) OR (buenos) OR (sentimientos))
```

So, the problem is that this query returns always zero results but if I remove manually the (suposed to be stopwords) "y" and "de" it works as expected and returns some thousands results using this query:

```
((mayor) OR (buenos) OR (sentimientos))
```

Before asking here I've tried:

- Avoid phrase splitting and OR query building and search for the full prase "mayor y de buenos sentimientos" Vs. "mayor buenos sentimientos", zero results Vs thousands :/
- Search in google
- Search in stackoverflow
- As I've read around I tried to point to stopwords file using a full path but it isn't working since solr does not accept it outside the app scope by default
- Since I'm using django-haystack I've tried to perform the query using Solr's admin interface (same results)
- reindex the whole solr after every significant change

Bonus: I've tried to add the following analyzer as well and nothing changes

```
<filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords_es.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

Comment: When the search is executed, are you searching just this one field, or are you also searching other fields with different indexing and analysis? Applying stop word filtering to some fields and not others in a single search can be a Problem with dismax/edismax query parsing.

Comment: Hi @frances, the query just involves one field and appends the boost ^1.2 to the whole phrase, the final query sent to solr is like -> ((mayor) OR (y) OR (de) OR (buenos) OR (sentimientos)) mayor y de buenos sentimientos^1.2

Can the boost affect?

Comment: Since you don't have quotes around your phrase, my guess is that the boost will only affect the final word. You might try letting Solr apply more of the logic itself and see what happens. If you're using the standard/lucene query parser, add the `q.op="OR"` argument or if you're using edismax query parser, add the `mm=1` argument. Either one should create an OR-search without the need for splitting your query.

Comment: I don't want to make all queries to be an OR since I can have much more params to filter with, I just want an OR in the keyword section, but I've tried to change <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/> to ="OR" in my schema since docs says that q.op is just to override this conf, same result.

I've added double quotes on the boost part, now the query is: _((mayor) OR (y) OR (de) OR (buenos) OR (sentimientos)) "mayor y de buenos sentimientos"^1.2_ but the result is the same as I wrote on the question :( any other idea? Thanks a lot @frances

Comment: If, for testing purposes, you do `q.op=OR&q=mayor y de buenos sentimientos` does that _work_ and not meet your needs otherwise, or does it also not work? If you do the search without the boost clause does that work correctly? It may be a good idea to consider moving to a different query parser if you're using the standard/lucene parser (and it sounds like you are). With dismax or edismax you could move your filters to `fq` arguments, and your boost clause to a `bq` clause (though you _really_ shouldn't need it), and default your main query to OR searching.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention this on my last comment, I get results, but no one contains mayor *nor* buenos *nor* sentimientos, I pulled out the boost clause on this test.

I will give a try to change the query parser (You are right, I'm using the standard) and come back with fresh information, thanks again